# Zend_Db_Select LIKE clause

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select

How can I set this query

```
SELECT city_id FROM cities WHERE city_name LIKE "%Vicenza%"
```

using the **Zend_Db_Select** class?

Answer (score 10):

Since @Jerec's answer didn't mention it... in order to have the effect of:

```
LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%'
```

You'll need to add the extra modifiers to the variable like such:

```
// Correct way
->where("city_name LIKE ?", "%{$searchTerm}%")

// Wrong ways
->where("city_name LIKE %?%", $searchTerm)
->where("city_name LIKE '%?%'", $searchTerm)
```

Might seem obvious, but took me three attempts to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this method

```
   $select = $dbTable->select()
    ->from('cities', 'city_id')
    ->where('city_name LIKE ?', $searchTerm);
```

where $dbTable is an instance of an Zend_Db_Table class

Comment: Thanks :) What the **setIntegrityCheck** method does exactly?

Comment: `setIntegrityCheck` allows `Zend_Db_Table_Select` to select rows outside of it's initial table, so you don't need it at all :)